# how to enclose all the <img> tags with <p> tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html content having some `<img>` tags in it. I've to enclose all the `<img>`  tags in `<p>` tag. Is there any to do something like this.

Comment: Please provide example.

Answer (score -1):

```
str1='<img>abc</img><img>def</img>'

str1=str1.replace('<img>','<p><img>')
str1=str1.replace('</img>','</img></p>')
print str1
#<p><img>abc</img></p><p><img>def</img></p>
```